# JanusGraph Geo Index

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I have this behavior the first call returns values using JanusGraph query

```
JG.query().has("geo_shape", Geo.WITHIN,
            Geoshape.circle(12, 13, 100.0)).vertices().count()
```

while the next line doesn't return results !

```
 val c = JG.traversal().V().has("geo_shape",
            within(Geoshape.circle(12, 13, 100.0))).count().next()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [query examples](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/search-predicates.html#_query_examples) your query should look more like this:

```
JG.traversal().V().has("geo_shape",
    geoWithin(Geoshape.circle(12, 13, 100.0))).count().next()
```

Comment: I read this page multiple times without noticing it !!! :) Thanks 
Guess I need some rest